# http max-age Unable to solve the situation of disagreement between the client and the server side

Tags: http, nginx, browser-cache, cache-control

http max-age seems to be unable to solve the problem of client-server time inconsistency

The question is this:
In other words, Cache-Control: max-age = N takes precedence over Expires (most browsers now follow http1.1)

But when I test, the server time 100s slower than local time (for example, the local timestamp is now 200s, then the server timestamp is 100s)

I set the max-age of css in Nginx = 60, however, I found that when I accessed the css resource again within 60s, it returned 304. In theory, it should return 200 (from cache)

Solve, thank you
Test environment: Chrome 64.0.3282.186 (official version) (64-bit)

First request:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbpMW.png)

Follow-up request:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyntY.png)

Nginx configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blN5Q.png)